# NOT IN not working in google BigQuery standard sql

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I am using Google BigQuery,i am trying to find the 'userid's from 'table2' excluding the ones that are stored in 'table1' 2 or more times.
this is the code :

```
#standardSQL
WITH t100 AS (
SELECT count_table.userid 
From(
SELECT userid,COUNT(`project.dataset.table1`.userid) as notification_count 
FROM `project.dataset.table1`
 GROUP BY userid) as count_table 
where notification_count >= 2 
)

SELECT userid FROM `project.dataset.table2` WHERE userid NOT IN (SELECT userid  FROM t100)
```

the problem is that this is returning the 'userid's from 'table1' that are stored 2 or more times, i have tried adding `WHERE userid IS NOT NULL` to the `SELECT userid  FROM t100`, yet it made no difference.
and just so that everything is clearer, this :
`SELECT userid FROM t100`, is not empty and the results returned for some reason still show in the result of the first code above.

Comment: add "where user_id is not null" after FROM t100 and notification_count >= 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i have tried adding WHERE userid IS NOT NULL to the SELECT userid  FROM t100, yet it made no difference

This of course had no affect because when you do `COUNT(userid) as notification_count` it always returns 0 for userid  NULL thus was filtered out by `HAVING notification_count >= 2`
If you would use COUNT(1) instead  - that's where you would potentially get null userids in output of t100. So `userid is NULL` is definitelly not an issue here

As others pointed  - your query should work - so if you continue getting the problem  - you need to dig more in this issue and provide us with more details on it

Meantime, try below as yet another version of your (otherwise looking good) query

```
#standardSQL
WITH t100 AS (
  SELECT userid
  FROM `project.dataset.table1`
  GROUP BY userid
  HAVING COUNT(userid) >= 2 
)
SELECT userid
FROM `project.dataset.table2` AS t2
LEFT join t100 ON t100.userid = t2.userid
WHERE t100.userid IS NULL
```

Comment: this worked, i have no idea why my query did not work or why the queries other answers included did not work. but thanks .

Answer (score 4):

It's due to null handling. There was a similar post on our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=813) about `NOT IN` versus `NOT EXISTS`. The [documentation for IN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#in-operators) states:

> IN with a NULL in the IN-list can only return TRUE or NULL, never FALSE

To achieve the semantics that you want, you should use an anti semijoin (`NOT EXISTS`). For example,

```
#standardSQL
WITH t100 AS (
  SELECT
    userid,
    COUNT(userid) as notification_count 
  FROM `project.dataset.table1`
  GROUP BY userid
  HAVING notification_count >= 2 
)
SELECT userid
FROM `project.dataset.table2` AS t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t100 WHERE userid = t2.userid);
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but the OP states: "i have tried adding `WHERE userid IS NOT NULL` to the `SELECT userid  FROM t100`, yet it made no difference"

Comment: Either something else was incorrect in that version of the query or there is a bug, which seems unlikely.

Comment: you can check Mikhail Berlyant 's answer, it worked for some reason, neither my original query nor your answer or the first one worked, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this isn't working, but out of general principle, I never use `(not) in` in combination with a select statement. Rather, I would `left outer join` the subquery and filter on null values therein:

```
#standardSQL

with t100 as (
select
  count_table.userid

from(
select
  userid
  ,count(`project.dataset.table1`.userid) as notification_count 

from `project.dataset.table1`

group by
  userid
) as count_table 

where notification_count >= 2 
)

select
  t2.userid as userid

from `project.dataset.table2` t2
left outer join t100
  on t100.userid = t2.userid

where t100.userid is null
```